# Apart the two hop operation what other differences between Elasticsearch Node Client and Transport Client?

Tags: elasticsearch

This may have been answered before but I do think their is some other key difference between the two native clients worth mentioning. I summarize what I think is some key differences but also have some questions at the bottom.

The most common knowledge is that Node client joins the cluster as a node and that Transport client requires 2 hop operations.

To take it further "The Node Client connects to the cluster". Actually the Node Client joins the cluster as a node to create a full mesh cluster. I.e: There is two way communication between all the nodes including clients. So anyone can contact anyone. Better explained here: https://www.found.no/foundation/elasticsearch-networking/

The only difference between client node and data node is that the client node does not store data. People should also be aware that the Node client also binds listening ports for the tcp and http transports. This allows it to become a proxy so other clients can connect to it or to serve plugin sites.

The transport client is a client in the purest sense. It doesn't join the cluster and it does not do any kind of port binding and it cannot be connected to and it cannot serve plugin sites.

Also correct me if I'm wrong Node client can also do scatter gather.

1. Does the Transport client consider routing fields. So if we pass it a routing field we could avoid the two hop? I'm guessing no.
2. Does the transport client do scatter gather?

Comment: Even I guess passing a routing value to a transport client won't prevent from two hops for the very reason it does not know the cluster state. However even I have this question of what's the best use case of when to use what.